# How to generate unique id for non registered users?

Tags: php, sql, user-identification

I'm looking for a method to create unique and permanent ID-s for non-registered users in my webshop. I have a working solution if the user is registered:

```
CREATE TABLE user ( 'user_id' int(11) NOT NULL, 'first_name' varchar(100) NOT NULL, 'last_name' varchar(100) NOT NULL, 'register_date' datetime DEFAULT NULL) 

CREATE TABLE cart ('cart_id' int(11) NOT NULL,'user_id' int(11) NOT NULL, 'item_id' int(11) NOT NULL) 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $cart->addToCart($_POST['user_id'], $_POST['item_id']);
      }
  }
```

Otherwise I have no way to know which cart belongs to whom. I'm trying to use cookies but any kind of advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing you could do is simply refer to the [session id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) (or equivalent). You mostly just want to identify the guest user, so, any id token would do the job.
If your question is "how do i generate unique ids" instead, then look for "uuid".